# Single activity Fragment based app and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got the app, that uses practcally just one activity. There is main area where I put fragments into. But what about back button now?

Of course I can override `onBackPressed()` but with what?

I'm pushing a fragment into it's holder using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method every time. I might be lacking understanding of a subject, but shouldn't there be some fragment built-in stack, that would allow me to point `onBackPressed()` to the previous fragment in stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not override onBackPress. You can add any fragment transaction to back stack. [There is special method to do this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29)